# Crystal Reports clipping data on export to Excel

Tags: crystal-reports, export-to-excel

I'm using Crystal Reports XI.

One of the text fields exports only data visible in the field. Other fields are fine: it doesn't matter what size are the fields on the design, they will still export full content to excel.

This is the only field I know that behaves this way. The only way I could find to preserve the data is to either:

1. expand the field to accommodate the longest possible description (which is not always possible even on A2 size), or
2. allow the field to grow (which results in exporting to multiple lines).

Is there any way to stop data from being clipped?

Comment: Are you exporting to a table or your report has more complex layout ?

Comment: It's a simple grid of data. There's some grouping and calculations per group, but only group footer with the summaries is displayed. The layout of the report is designed to be exported to excel.